# JFrog npm install fails

Tags: npm, artifactory

In Jfrog Artifactory, I created a read only user and tried to access a remote NPM package which is part of NodeJS repository.
For example 
`npm install @angular/material` and the package fails to download it with the following **error**:

```
The user is part of a read only group.
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 Forbidden:@angular/material@^5.2.5
```

Can someone please suggest where we can I set the read permissions for the user?

This is an already existing user with which other python artifacts are successfully installed .

Even npm local repositories are installed successfully but npm remote repositories fetched from npm registry are giving errors

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer myself Enabling the Upload/Cache permission in JFROG Artifactory fixed the issue. 
As per the JFROG help
READ: Allows only downloading of artifacts 
Upload/Cache: Allows uploading artifacts to local repository and caching artifacts from remote repositories. 
Since downloading artifacts from remote needs remote caching this permission is not available for the READ permission users .